# How to get data in Webscraping Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

https://mor.nlm.nih.gov/RxNav/search?searchBy=NDC&searchTerm=51079045120

how to get RXCUI number from this website in python, I am unable to get

```
content = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
cont = soup.findAll("div", {"id": "titleHolder"})
rx = cont.find("span", id = "rxcuiDecoration")
print(rx.text)
```

Comment: Just in addition - In newer code avoid old syntax `findAll()` instead use `find_all()` - For more take a minute to [check docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names)

Answer (score 1):

The site renders using javascript you have to use the API

```py
import requests 

r = requests.get('https://rxnav.nlm.nih.gov/REST/ndcstatus.json?caller=RxNav&ndc=51079045120')

print(r.json()['ndcStatus']['rxcui'])
```

Comment: Thank You for this, 

can you also please the tell that how to get "Ingredients and Strength" values from status section of that

https://mor.nlm.nih.gov/RxNav/search?searchBy=NDC&searchTerm=51079045120

Comment: https://rxnav.nlm.nih.gov/REST/rxcui/197361/historystatus.json?caller=RxNav